# Кликнуть по javacript(void(0)) с помощью Awesomium browser на C#

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

Ситуация следующая.
Есть сайт. Пишу под него авторизацию на шарпе с помощью Awesomium.
При переходе на главную страницу отображается форма с регистрацией.

Чтобы переключить на другую форму, мне необходимо кликнуть по "кнопке" LOGIN, которая в свою очередь заключена в .

В свою очередь я открыл FF и там есть events на эту кнопку, а именно 4 события на jquery, которые и переключают с одной формы на другую.

Первая:

```
function() {
$('.top-bar').removeClass('expanded');
}
```

Вторая:

```
function() {
  $('#signup_form').hide();
  $('#homepage_login_button').hide();
  $('#homepage_signup_button').show();
  $('#login_form').fadeIn();
}
```

Третья:

```
function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#new_home").offset().top - 40
  }, 800);
}
```

Четвертая:

```
q = m.handle = function(a) {
  return typeof k === aa || a && k.event.triggered === a.type ? g : k.event.dispatch.apply(q.elem, arguments)
}
```

А внутри  есть ещё a href ссылка(со значением: javascript:void(0); и внутри a href имеет значение - LOGIN), которая также имеет несколько events, а именно:

1.

```
function() {
  $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
}
```

2.

```
q = m.handle = function(a) {
  return typeof k === aa || a && k.event.triggered === a.type ? g : k.event.dispatch.apply(q.elem, arguments)
}
```

Вопрос: как мне кликнуть на эту кнопочку такую? Заставить выполниться все функции?

Answer (score 1):

Находите кнопку с помощью jquery к примеру, и вызываете $('.login').click, или $('.login').trigger('click') на крайняк $('.login').mousedown().mouseup()

Если на сайте нет jquery можно его подключить, к примеру так:

```
var jQ = false;
function initJQ() {
  if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
    if (!jQ) {
      jQ = true;
      document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    }
    setTimeout('initJQ()', 50);
  } else {
    (function($) {
    $(function() {

      // здесь пишем jQuery код

    })
    })(jQuery)
  }
}
initJQ();
```